# mpm-itk installation -- make: missing: Command not found on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I'm  installing `mpm-itk` for apache 2.4 on ubuntu.

Steps:

1. Download from http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/ tar.gz file
2. Extract them
3. Run `./configure && make && sudo make install`

The error I get:

```
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking for cap_init in -lcap... no
    checking for --with-apxs... no
    checking for apxs... missing
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: config.h is unchanged
    missing -c mpm_itk.c seccomp.c
    make: missing: Command not found
    make: *** [mpm_itk.la] Error 127
```

Comment: Try to copy the error message (`make: missing: Command not found`) and paste it in Google. You'll be surprised how fast you can find the solution.

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja, of course i did this and not finding solutions for this problem i created this post.

Comment: First result in Google after searching the above: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192645/make-command-not-found If you actually tried it, tell us about what you did and what failed.

Comment: I read information on this link. And not worked for me. I don't have problem with make and build-essential. I have problem with: missing: Command not found.

Comment: @ConstantinePopov It's very unlikely that the command is literally called "missing". If anything it looks like the Makefile is just a bit broken.

Comment: @Chris I'm think this problem with mpm-itk Make file after ./confugure. First strings this file: ```APXS=missing
SRCS=mpm_itk.c seccomp.c
HDRS=seccomp.h mpm_default.h```

Comment: Is apxs installed? That's what it seems to be complaining about.

Comment: Assuming you are building Apache from source, you probably need to specify the path to apxs.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. It's work for me. I'm reinstall apache ```sudo apt-get install apache2-dev``` after this i'm run ```./configure```  and i have correct path to APXS in Make file.

Comment: You need to install aspx, i don't know the package for ubuntu, but for Amazon AMI it's "httpd24-devel"

Answer (score 0):

Install "make" command and try again.

```
apt-get install make
```

Comment: No. This I have already installed. As you can see from post i have problem with "missing" command

Comment: Okay, could you confirm you have installed  all the packages needed to build your code

sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: I believe you can install mpm-itk with the help of apt-get; 
$ sudo apt-cache search apache2-mpm-itk

apache2-mpm-itk - transitional itk MPM package for apache2
libapache2-mpm-itk - multiuser module for Apache


sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk

Comment: Not worked for me. Because i need  apache 2.4. If i use apache2-mpm-itk from ubuntu repositories for this package need apache2.2.  
```apache2-mpm-itk : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```

Answer (score 0):

When running ./configure you need to add the prefix for apxs. If apxs it isn't part of your PATH it won't get picked up and you get the "missing" error

`./configure --with-apxs=WHERE_YOU_INSTALLED_APACHE/bin/apxs`

e.g. for me

`./configure --with-apxs=/etc/httpd/bin/apxs`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need apxs, which isn't installed with apache2 in ubuntu, to get it run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

Then repeat step 3.